# retrieving elements from resultset object

Tags: java, sql, servlets, jdbc

I want retrieve blob elements from resultset object and I want to display all the images from database one by one in a single window.

below is my database table.

```
| application_name | varchar(45)  | 
| application_id   | varchar(10)  | 
| application_path | varchar(500) | 
| application_icon | blob         |
```

below is my code servlet code for retrieval of images from database

### Image.java

```
response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
        try {
            Connection connection= DBUtil.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement=connection.prepareStatement("select application_icon  from application_master where application_path='abc'");
            ResultSet resultSet=preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            int i=1;
            //out.print("<h1>photo</h1>");
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                /*out.print("<img width='200' height='200' src="+resultSet.getBlob(1)+ ">  </img>" );*/
                Blob blob=resultSet.getBlob(i);
                response.setContentLength((int) blob.length());
                InputStream inputStream=blob.getBinaryStream();
                OutputStream outputStream=response.getOutputStream();
                byte buf[]=new byte[(int) blob.length()];
                inputStream.read(buf);
                outputStream.write(buf);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("displayed");
                i=i+1;
                System.out.println(i);
            }
```

The above code retrieve image and display image from 1st row.when  i becomes 2 i.e i=2.It shows exception "java.sql.SQLException: Column Index out of range, 2 > 1. ".

I am not understanding when the query "select application_icon  from application_master where application_path='abc'" is executed it returns more than one images.........then how can I retrieve all the images from the resultset object.

If I am not correct please correct me..........

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `.getBlob(1)`, not `.getBlob(i)`. The BLOB data is always in column 1 for each row that the `resultSet` object returns.

Comment: ok..then how can I retrieve all the images from the resultset object..........any idea

Comment: Your `resultSet` object will return a single column, so you always use `.getBlob(1)`, meaning "return the data from column 1 of the current row as a BLOB object". Each iteration through your `while` loop will return a different image (as retrieved by the `.next()` method).

Comment: @rajeev Gord Thompson answer is correct, you should accept it. if you have any doubt with the answer mention it in comment.